# Elastic Search SSL Certificate Expiry

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, ssl-certificate, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

I'm new to Elastic search. Integrated my Spring boot application with Elastic search through `Java High Level Rest Client` and I've enabled security by providing below properties after setting up the certificate and passwords:

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
```

**Will this certificate expire? If yes, then how to handle this scenario in production?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. By default, the CA and Certificate expire in 3 years.

You can hit below GET API as per [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-ssl.html) for checking the Expiry:

```
GET /_ssl/certificates
```

Comment: Thanks for the providing documentation reference!

Answer (score 3):

As per my R&D: **The self-signed SSL certificate generated through "elasticsearch-certutil" expires after 3 years once created, we will need to deploy new certificates then.**

Answer (score 1):

In case you won't have all the results in kibana with the API mentioned above, you can check manually with the following:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in **/path/to/cert/cert.p12** -clcerts -nodes -passin
   pass: | openssl x509 -noout -enddate
```

This works with `.p12` certificates. The output will look like this in centos7:

```
MAC verified OK
notAfter=Nov 14 08:48:50 2024 GMT
```